# Failed to run simple akka sample using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I'm just following akka sample but could not run the program.

1. I've installed akka, sbt(0.13), scala(2.10.3) using homebrew(OSX Mountail Lion)
2. make empty directory named **akka_test**
3. create [build.sbt](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html) and [Hello.scala](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/hello-world.html) file
4. run sbt in akka_test directory and **compile** command worked well
5. sbt's **run** command complains *No main class detected*

What should I do to run the program?

here's my code

build.sbt

```
name := "My Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies +=
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.1"
```

Hello.scala

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props

class HelloWorld extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    // create the greeter actor
    val greeter = context.actorOf(Props[Greeter], "greeter")
    // tell it to perform the greeting
    greeter ! Greeter.Greet
  }

  def receive = {
    // when the greeter is done, stop this actor and with it the application
    case Greeter.Done ⇒ context.stop(self)
  }
}

object Greeter {
  case object Greet
  case object Done
}

class Greeter extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Greeter.Greet ⇒
      println("Hello World!")
      sender ! Greeter.Done
  }
}
```

Comment: Try Typesafe Activator and the Hello Akka tutorial: http://akka.io/downloads/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sbt run looks for a "main" class, i.e., a class with `def main(args: Array[String])` or extends the trait `App`.  Since that can't be an actor, you'll need to initiate a system and use that to initiate HelloWorld, so something like:

```
class HelloWorldMain {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        import akka.actor.ActorSystem
        val system = ActorSystem("HelloWorld")
        val helloWorldActor = system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld] ...)
        // ... Do stuff
    }
}
```

Since systems just run until you shut them down, if you want your main class to stop you'll either have to use futures via `akka.pattern.ask` and have the system terminate after you collect them or set up a separate reaper actor to kill the system for you.  [This post](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) has more info on how to do that, and [this pull request](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/1370) is a good example of how it looks in practice (and has some other useful stuff in there as well)

Answer (score 13):

sbt has `run-main` command which accepts main class from command line,
so full command is

```
sbt "run-main akka.Main HelloWorld"
```

Comment: On my sbt it is failing with message "Expected whitespace character". The version it accepts `sbt "run-main akka.Main HelloWorld"` (with quotes).

Answer (score 4):

in case you have package you need to add the path.
For example if you have package com.foo.bar
(your HelloWorld is in ./youProject/src/main/scala/com/foo/bar)
then the command will be:

```
sbt "run-main akka.Main com.foo.bar.HelloWorld"
```